# What format for external file so that R can read a list of lists?

Tags: r

I have a haskell program that produces a text file, which is then read by R. My current solution is working, but I am asking if there is a better solution and whether it is worth changing the current approach.

Currently my haskell program produces the following output (simplified example):

```
mylist <- list(
list(c("b"),c("b","E"),c("b","E","P"),c("b","T"),c("b","P","T"),c("b","E","T"),c("b","E","P","T"))
, list(c("b"),c("b","T"),c("b","N"),c("b","E"),c("b","E","T"),c("b","N","T"),c("b","N","E"),c("b","N","E","T"))
, list(c("b","N"),c("b","E","N"),c("b","N","T"),c("b","E","N","T"))
)
myListNames <- c("Name1","Name2","Name3")
```

This output is saved to a text file that is simply sourced from within R. I then access the two variables `mylist` and `myListNames`.

The data: I am generating 9 text files. List entries represent a feature, there are at maximum 120 different features and the name can be 20 characters long. Please note that features have nothing to do with statistics. In the dummy example `b` would be in the real world example 20 character long. Each sublist is about 5 to 45 elements long, but an outlier might have 500.000 list entries.

The current approach works reasonably well. But is there another way to store a list of lists as a text file that might be better suited?

Comment: you can output it to JSON which would be more versatile.   However, if this your goal is simply to get the data into `R`, then what is wrong with your current approach?    Is there anything it is not doing that you would like it to do?

Comment: yaml is a nice format for this - you can import it using the package with same name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the approach that was suggested by Ricardo Saporta. It worked like a charm and I used the R library `RJSONIO` for JSON parsing in R.

Many thanks to Ricardo Saporta!